# Accessing a private field from one class to another not related to the former class in C++ (OOP)

Tags: c++, oop, field, private

I have 2 classes  - `A and B`. Class `A` has a member `list<int>` and a method `addData()` that adds a number to this list. The second class `B` has a function `displayContent()` - it iterates through the list of the class `A` and prints its content (the added numbers). The problem I face is that I cannot access the `private`(cannot be changed to public) field `list` of class `A` from the newly instantiated object (from class `B`). I would like to ask how can this be achieved with `getters/setters`, or  a `copy constructor`?

Comment: `//identifier 'a' is undefined?` - you didn't pass an instance of A as a variable and B is not a child of A, so how can `a` be defined?

Answer (score 4):

In displayContent_a, your identified 'a' is undefined, because within that function or class you have never declared a variable 'a'. A simple solution is to pass an object of type A to the function which determines what A object to display the list of:

```
void displayContent_a(A& a) {
        //this uses the a from the parameter
        for (auto x = a.a.begin(); x != a.a.end(); x++) { //use a.a because we want to access the list 
            cout << *x << endl;
        }

    }
```

However, this won't be enough, as B can't access private data of A. To fix this, you have to make B a friend of A. This can be done in the following way:

```
class B; //forward declare B so it can be used in friend declarations in A

class A
{
//... your content

    friend class B;
}
```

Comment: Removed my answer. He asks it to be done with a copy constructor, which is impossible as far a I know.

Comment: I don't see how a copy constructor would be involved with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In good code classes are never entangled. This means that if class `B` uses class `A` than class `A` shouldn't have any knowledge about `B`.
So adding a friendship is just a workaround which makes code entangled.

It is hard to say what is best approach without knowing more context, but there are couple possibilities.

You can add such API to A:

```
class A {
public:
    void forEach(std::function<void(int)> f) const {
        for(auto x : mData) {
            f(x);
        }
    }

private:
    list<int> mData;
};

class B {
public:
    void displayContent(std::ostream &out) {
        a.forEach([&out](int x){ out << x<< ", "; });
    }

private:
    A a;
};
```

Advantage is that you can change lots of thing in `A` (for example change list to vector) and you do not have to fix anything in `B`.

There are more possibilities. Simple getter could solve issue:

```
class A {
public:
    list<int> getData() const {
        return mData;
    }

private:
    list<int> mData;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To access variable 'a' of class A, it is not possible with current implementation.

Firstly, make class B as the derived class of base class A

Even then, it is not possible to access the private variable of class A from anywhere outside even from derived class.

Try to implement by declaring variable as protected.

Another implementation can be by declaring class B as friend of class A.
That way, private variables can be accessed from class B

Answer (score 0):

A getter is a member function which allows the member attribute `List<int> L` to be read from outside of the object.
In class A define:

```
public:
   List<int> getList(){
      return L;
     }
```

Now you can add In Class B:

```
A a(constructor args);
List<int>=a.getList();
```

in the same measure you can use setters to change the value of private attributes e.g

```
 public:
    void setList(List<int> data){
        L=data;
       }
```